# Espocrm. Сохранение файла на сервер

Tags: php, crm

Разрабатываю кастумную API для *ESPO CRM*. Возникла проблема сохранения файлов на сервер через *JSON-запрос*. Сначала пробовала через *EntitiyManager*, но он не сохраняет сам файл, а только создаёт элемент сущности. Может кто работал с этой crm и может подсказать как делали это?

Answer (score 0):

Нашла пару способов:

1. Через *FileStorage\Manager*. Он сохраняет файл, но не обрабатывает как необходимо. Закодированный код он обратно не декодирует в картину, и на странице с этим вложением увидишь непонятную картинку.
2. Через сущность *Espo\Services\Attachment*, файл обрабатывался как нужно, но все равно почему-то не получалось его нормально отобразить.
   Из-за жатых сроков пришлось прийти не к самой лучшей идеи. Через curl отправляла вложения в сущность Attachment и там это вложение обрабатывалось как надо.
   Мб, кому-то и пригодится это.